Is it possible to get a "footcite" in RevTeX?
A few decades ago, bibliographies in papers used to be way shorter than they are today, and some journals used to use footnote bibliographies. For example, consider Lee & Yang's 1956 Phys. Rev. 104 B516, which is free-to-read (and hence a good example, I believe). The paper has no bibliography section and the references are given as separate footnotes. Whenever a new reference is cited, a footnote is added to the page where it is first cited with all the relevant bibliographical data. Instead of listing the references at the end, you add the whole bibliography entry as a footnote.
I'd like to know whether it is possible to mimic/force this behavior with modern RevTeX. While in modern papers with dozens of references this is a terrible idea, I recently found myself writing a document with no more than a couple of references, and to have a bibliography seemed unnecessary.
To make it clear, this is not meant to be done in a journal, in which the editors will eventually format the paper however they like. I'd like to create this behavior in my personal documents. I'd like to keep the RevTeX distribution to enjoy the other features and overall Physical Review appearance.
